# Camera takePicture does not always do jpeg callback depending on picture size

Tags: android, callback, android-camera, resolution

I am with stuck problem where `camera.takePicture()` jpeg callback gets less frequently called where desired picture size is higher. E.g. it always succeedes with 640x480, but only works on 5% to 40% of cases with minor parameter tweaks with 3264x2448 resolution. 
Relevant code:

```
public void foo(View view) {
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
            camera.release();
            Toast.makeText(SurvCamActivity.getInstance(), "jpeg callback", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    //Gets desired resolution
    SpinnerResolution res = getSelectedSpinnerResolution();
    Camera camera = getCameraInstance();
    try {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setPictureSize(res.width, res.height);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(R.layout.fragment_preview));
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Now odd thing is, if I add breakpoint to `camera.takePicture()` and simply resume execution once thread reaches there it always calls the jpeg callback. When I added `Thread.sleep(700)` after the `camera.takePicture()` it also started consistently doing the callbacks. Any ideas? Tested on Nexus 4.

Comment: What is the logic that calls `foo()`? You cannot you call `camera.takePicture()` in `foo()` before `jpegCallback.onPictureTaken()` is started.

Comment: foo is button onclick function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Turns out the camera object might have got garbage collected. I created static reference to it and now it works without problems.

Comment: I don't know why you insist on releasing the camera every time. Maybe you can achieve shorter lag if you keep it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `camera.takePicture()` again before `jpegCallback.onPictureTaken()` is started, so you need to throttle the `button.onClick()`. You can probably reduce he lag if you keep the camera in preview mode all the time.

Comment: Problem with this approach is exception should already happen on `camera.getParameters()` because next `button.onClick()` couldn't get hold of camera instance because it was already in use. It also doesn't explain why callback isn't initiated when only one button click is made.